# Google Maps within an app with restricted key doesn't work

Tags: android, google-directions-api

I have an android app that renders a MapView and polylines, which works fine on the Android emulator if I use an IP restricted API key, but doesn't even display a map, and definitely no polylines, when I use an android restricted key with the expo built application running on my phone.

I have the following in my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "package": "com.company.project",
      "permissions": [ "CAMERA" ],
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "ACTUAL_API_KEY_HERE"
        }
      }
    },
...
```

The directions portion of the code is as follows:

```
        const key = Constants.manifest.android.config.googleMaps.apiKey;
        const resp = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${ startLoc }&destination=${ destinationLoc }&key=${ key }`);
        const respJson = await resp.json();
```

I am building my app with the following command:

expo build:android

I then download the apk from expo.io.

The key is restricted to android apps in the GCP console.  I have verified that the package name in my app.json matches the name in the restriction and I get the SHA-1 fingerprint from the "expo fetch:android:hashes" command.

As I said, this works fine in the emulator (with an IP restricted key) but not when running on my phone.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Check you use meta data in Manifest file like that..

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, this is in the AndroidManifest.xml under android/src/main.

Comment: Please accept this answer as you think your problem is solved .It will inspire me

Comment: This was already in my AndroidManifest.xml, so it didn't fix the problem.